# Does Nexus One WiFi traffic go through Google?

Tags: wi-fi, browser, google, data-monitoring, privacy

When I use the default browser (what is it? Is it Chrome? Firefox? other?) to view a site (not necessarily via Google search), does any of that visit information reach Google servers?

How about DNS?

Comment: The default browser is custom for Android, separate from Chrome.

Comment: Why would it? Are you using google for DNS?

Comment: @Uninspired: many people probably do, they type "android stackexchange" instead of "android.stackexchange.com"

Comment: @Lie: That's just a search result. Once you click through the domain lookups and traffic aren't involved with Google anymore (unless it's a Google site on the other end). The traffic is going to be on your Carrier (if you're using 3G) or your ISP (if you're using wifi).

Comment: As an aside Firefox Mobile is now available in Android Market if you'd rather use that http://www.appbrain.com/app/mozilla-firefox-web-browser/org.mozilla.firefox

Comment: @Al Everett: Precisely, many people (e.g. me) are just too lazy to remember the URLs of websites, and just use Google search result as a "domain name server" (loosely speaking).

Comment: @Al If you've ever seen search engine stats you'd see that very few people know the difference between the URL bar and the search box on the default home page. I cringe and try to explain when I see my non-technical friends type something like www.facebook.com into the Google Search box and then select the first result instead of just typing it into the URL bar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually the predictive search from the address bar sends the text you enter to Google to provide the search predictions. For example, if you start to type "search" and get to "sea" it suggests "sears", "seattle times", "sean parker" etc...

Comment: You can configure that "Settings > Search > Google Search settings > Show web suggestions"

Answer (score 4):

No, the data shouldn't pass through Google servers unless you are viewing a site hosted by Goolge.